# Is there a way to edit a question (or answer) without bumping it?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-deferred, bumping

Whenever I edit a question or answer, the question gets bumped.  In other words it appears at the top of the list.  Sometimes I just want to make an edit without having it pushed up to the top of the queue.

Is there an option somewhere that I'm missing that would allow me to do that?  Sometimes I'm a bit reluctant to make minor edits on poorly worded - and often old - questions, realizing that it will push them to the top of the list.

**I think SE should provide a this-is-a-minor-edit checkbox on the edit page.**

When checked, it would update the date of last modification as it does now.  However, behind the scenes SE should implement a "date of last major modification" and have that used to sort the questions.  When someone performs an edit without checking the checkbox, both the last-modification date and the last-major-modification date would be updated.  If the checkbox is checked, only the last-modification date would be updated.

The benefit of this would be major cleanup, or tagging campaigns would not cause the edited posts to rise to the top of the queue.  The last-modification date displayed beneath a post would show when it was last modified, even if the modification was minor.

Comment: No, looks like it is based on time stamps http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page

Comment: Some wiki systems have an option to indicate "this is a minor edit" that prevents the system from highlighting it as a new update. It would be nice if SE sites had the same feature.

Comment: I tagged this as `feature-request`. It sure would be nice to not have *everything* bump to top of queue. I also recognize it's a hard problem to address properly. e.g. What if someone marks an edit as "minor, please ignore", when it really isn't, and fundamentally changes the meaning?

Comment: Relevant: there is a fair bit of furore right now on appropriate specificity and rate of tagging (http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/is-this-a-reasonable-way-to-use-tags-on-arcgis-questions).

Comment: @mattwilkie I was thinking if we have one of those cleanup campaigns it would be nice to have everyone doing it in a way that didn't bump everything to the top.  I realize probably few people would use it (and end up bumping as it does now).  But if we could get some of the more active editors to use this, then maybe there would be less reluctance to make minor edits to old questions.

Comment: I share the concern over abuses of a "minor edit" option. Perhaps it should be limited to users with a certain amount of reputation? Maybe double the reputation one needs to make edits that don't require review?

Comment: I doubt this request could be approved as it stands, because it is too easy to abuse. (Malicious people could go through and make wholesale damaging changes to old threads; this might not be noticed for a long time.) A modification might be workable, though: by marking something as "minor" you would not have it automatically take effect, but instead go into a review queue accessible only to high-rep users.  Upon their approval it would take effect without bumping the thread.  The main problem with that is the additional work involved for the community.

Comment: I just set [meta-tag:status-deferred] on this because it can only be declined/implemented at the [meta.se] rather than [meta.gis.se] level.

Comment: The SE team frequently visits all meta sites. I think it is not necessary bumping post on GIS meta just to add that tag. I'd rather prefer moderators to not add tags in posts where the subject is beyond their reach. This is just my opinion though. (@PolyGeo).

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting answer as a Comment on one of the Answers to [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page) over at Meta StackOverflow which is from @JeffAttwood who says:

> there is zero way to do this that doesn't involve hidden abuse and
>   sweeping changes under the rug. The answer is right in front of you:
>   click "Questions" instead of browsing the home page, if you know you
>   want to avoid recent changes. In other words, YOU need to opt out of
>   viewing changes for YOU, rather than dictating it for all other users.

After landing on my own [User](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo) page, I always click [Questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions) or more often [Unanswered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered) to find the questions likely to interest me and so I never see "bumping issues".

[image]

I am assuming now that others must instead often land [here at the home/front page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) to see "bumping" as an issue.

Comment: Bumping will remain an issue as long as the default system behavior is to load the home page when going to gis.stackexhange.com, including any time the GIS title banner is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by Mapperz, Shog's answer on:

[Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)

says there is no way to edit without bumping the question (despite he says also that not all edits go to the front page).

If you search on MSO by [[editing] bumping is:question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bediting%5D+bumping+is%3Aquestion)  one will see a lot of interesting threads tagged as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) with suggestions to avoid bumping in some situations of minor edits, retags and other.

One suggestion I can think of would be to separate the active tab in two groups.

For example:

1. New answers (maybe including when a answer is accepted too).
2. Edits on questions and existing answers and retags.